# import objc in embedded python in a C++ thread

Tags: c++, python, multithreading, boost

I am new to embedding python in C++ application. Please forgive me if this has been asked before, even though I did my homework by searching through the web.

So, here is my problem. 
If I ran the embedded python code in the application's main thread, everything runs fine. But if I ran the embedded python code in the child thread ( created by main thread ), some of the python import will not work.

I made a small program here to demonstrate:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

int threadFunc ( ){
    PyGILState_STATE gstate;
    gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

    std::cout << "Py_GetProgramName: " << Py_GetProgramName() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Py_GetPath: " << Py_GetPath() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Py_GetExecPrefix: " << Py_GetExecPrefix() << std::endl;

    object main_module = boost::python::import ( "__main__");
    object main_namespace = main_module.attr("__dict__");

    object objc_import = boost::python::import ( "objc" );

    exec("a = 10\n", main_namespace);
    exec("print a\n", main_namespace);

    return 0;

}

int main( ){

    Py_InitializeEx( 0 ); // 

    PyEval_InitThreads();

    // Uncomment this will make the program work.
    //object objc_import = boost::python::import ( "objc" );

    PyEval_ReleaseLock();

    boost::thread * theChildThread = new boost::thread (threadFunc);

    while (1){
        boost::this_thread::sleep( boost::posix_time::seconds(1) );
    }
    delete theChildThread;

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

The code fails when I tries to import objc in the threadFunc

```
object objc_import = boost::python::import ( "objc" );
```

By experiment different things, I find that if I do this in the main thread before starting child thread, the whole program would work ( see comments in the main function ):

```
//Uncomment this will make the program work.
//object objc_import = boost::python::import ( "objc" );
```

I am wondering what happened there. Is there anyway to without importing objc in main thread, but still make the child thread work?

Thanks,

Comment: I removed the objective-c tag because your question is dealing with C++ and not objective-c.  In hindsight I realize that "objc" is a bridge module between Python and Objective-C (http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/).  So are you trying to build a C++ program or Objective-C program on a Mac?

Comment: It looks like Negative Zero is building a C++ program that uses python as its primary scripting language, which just happens to make use of ObjC.  It's python using ObjC, not NegativeZero.

Comment: @Arafangion So do you think I should put the tag back again?

Comment: @PeterM: I think it's borderline.  I think it should probably go in, however, most people using that tag would assume that means an ObjC project, not a project that merely happens to use ObjC frameworks.

Comment: it's python using Objc bridge. And I am trying to embed that python in the C++ program. Yes. it's on Mac OS